# Error running tez in hive. Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, hive, apache-tez

- Hadoop 3.3.5
- Hive 3.1.3
- Tez 0.10.2

I follow the instruction in this link to build tez 0.10.2 for hadoop 3.3.5: https://tez.apache.org/install.html

The db is stored on s3 bucket and I am able to run 'select count(*) from m1.t1' using hive.execution.engine=mr.

When I set hive.execution.engine=tez, and run the same query, I got this error immediately:

```
2023-02-15T21:21:09,208  INFO [a6e2cd1a-b2c9-42d8-9568-8e0b64677f77 main] client.TezClient: App did not succeed. Diagnostics: Application application_1676506240754_0019 failed 2 times due to AM Contai
ner for appattempt_1676506240754_0019_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2023-02-15 21:21:08.730]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1676506240754_0019_02_000001
Exit code: 1
[2023-02-15 21:21:08.732]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster
[2023-02-15 21:21:08.733]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster
```

If I set tez.use.cluster.hadoop-libs to true in tez-site.xml, I got YARN running but failed with load aws credential error even I have set the fs.s3a credentials in hadoop's core-site.xml, hive's hive-site.xml and .bashrc environment variables.

```
keys are masked to show sample only:

echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
I9U996400005XXXXXXXX
echo $AWS_SECRET_KEY
mPY8GiU6NegNWoVnaODXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

hive> set hive.execution.engine=tez;
hive> select count(*) from m1.t1;
Query ID = hdp-user_20230215210146_62ed9fab-5d4a-42a9-bf54-5fb6f84a9048
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1676506240754_0015)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1            container  INITIALIZING     -1          0        0       -1       0       0
Reducer 2        container        INITED      1          0        0        1       0       0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 00/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 2.03 s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1676506240754_0015_3_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1676506240754_0015_3_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: t1 initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1676506240754_0015_3_00 [Map 1], java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://hadoop-cluster/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/m1.db/t1: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

Tried to add all fs.s3a properties from core-site.xml to tez-site.xml and set fs,s3a,access.key and set fs.s3a.secret.key= inside hive session but still get same error.

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

Question: according to tez install instruction

Ensure tez.use.cluster.hadoop-libs is not set in tez-site.xml, or if it is set, the value should be false

But when set to false, tez could not run.
When set to true, I got aws credential error even though I set them in every possible location or environment variables.

==========================================================
Update:
Not sure if this is the right answer to this problem but I finally got it working by adding this property to hive-site.xml

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.conf.hidden.list</name>
    <value>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword,hive.server2.keystore.password,fs.s3a.proxy.password,dfs.adls.oauth2.credential,fs.adl.oauth2.credential</value>
</property>
```

Default all fs.s3a credential are hidden config even you don't set this property. I explicitly add this property and remove all fs.s3a credential related from the value.
Now, I can run select count(*) with tez.

Answer (score 0):

> I got YARN running but failed with load aws credential

Hive removes the properties in `hive.conf.hidden.list` from job configuration before submitting any job to YARN. So, in your case, the missing properties `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` cause `No AWS Credentials provided`.

Please see S3 filesystem related properties under `hive.conf.hidden.list` [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java#L5522-L5528);

```
+ ",fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId"
+ ",fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey"
+ ",fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId"
+ ",fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey"
+ ",fs.s3a.access.key"
+ ",fs.s3a.secret.key"
+ ",fs.s3a.proxy.password"
```

Your update solves the issue, and I think it is the correct solution. But, just for you to know, now you are exposing the S3 key passwords in various logs files. Some of the files that I know are as below;

Hive -> `<HIVE_HOME>/logs/<user>/webhcat/webhcat.log.<date>`

Hadoop -> `<HADOOP_HOME>/logs/userlogs/application_<app#>/container_<container#>/history.txt.appattempt_<app#>`

If you have access to source code, you can modify this [method](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConfUtil.java#L132) not to yield the mentioned properties in hive logs.